# Custom Shader SCNProgram iOS 9 Scenekit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios9, scenekit, fragment-shader

I am trying to mess around in `SceneKit` and teach myself it. Basically, I am creating a quad with 3 rectangular sides and 1 sloping slide.

I want my texture on it to stretch and warp/deform across the surface.

Reading some stuff online, it seems that I need to make an `SCNProgram` with custom vertex and fragment shaders to get the effect. But, I can't seem to get the texture to spread across the surface. Need help please. (I am new to graphics programming hence trying to teach it to myself).

My Swift code to create the geometry and texture it is as follows:

```
func geometryCreate() -> SCNNode {  

    let verticesPosition = [  
        SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),  
        SCNVector3Make(5.0, 0.0, 0.0),  
        SCNVector3Make(5.0, 5.0, 0.0),  
        SCNVector3Make(0.0, 3.0, 0.0)  
    ]  
    let textureCord =    [CGPoint (x: 0.0,y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0,y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0,y: 1.0), CGPoint(x: 0.0,y: 1.0)]  

    let indices: [CInt] = [  
    0, 2, 3,  
    0, 1, 2  
    ]  

    let vertexSource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: verticesPosition, count: 4)  
    let srcTex = SCNGeometrySource(textureCoordinates: textureCord, count: 4)  
    let date = NSData(bytes: indices, length: sizeof(CInt) * indices.count)  

    let scngeometry = SCNGeometryElement(data: date, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.Triangles, primitiveCount: 2, bytesPerIndex: sizeof(CInt))  

    let geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [vertexSource,srcTex], elements: [scngeometry])  
    let program = SCNProgram()  

    if let filepath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("vertexshadertry", ofType: "vert") {  
        do {  
            let contents = try NSString(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String  
            program.vertexShader = contents  
        } catch {  
            print("**** happened loading vertex shader")  
        }  
    }  


    if let fragmentShaderPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fragshadertry", ofType:"frag")  
    {  
        do {  
        let fragmentShaderAsAString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: fragmentShaderPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)  
        program.fragmentShader = fragmentShaderAsAString as String  
        } catch {  
            print("**** happened loading frag shader")  
        }  
    }  
    program.setSemantic(SCNGeometrySourceSemanticVertex, forSymbol: "position", options: nil)  
    program.setSemantic(SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord, forSymbol: "textureCoordinate", options: nil)  
    program.setSemantic(SCNModelViewProjectionTransform, forSymbol: "modelViewProjection", options: nil)  
    do {  
        let texture = try GLKTextureLoader.textureWithCGImage(UIImage(named: "stripes")!.CGImage!, options: nil)  

        geometry.firstMaterial?.handleBindingOfSymbol("yourTexture", usingBlock: { (programId:UInt32, location:UInt32, node:SCNNode!, renderer:SCNRenderer!) -> Void in  
                glTexParameterf(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), Float(GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE) )  
                glTexParameterf(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), Float(GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE) )  
                glTexParameterf(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), Float(GL_LINEAR) )  
                glTexParameterf(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), Float(GL_LINEAR) )  
                glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture.name)  
        })  
    } catch {  
        print("Texture not loaded")  
    }  

    geometry.firstMaterial?.program = program  
    let scnnode = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)  
    return scnnode  

}
```

My Vertex shader is:

```
attribute vec4 position;  
attribute vec2 textureCoordinate;  
uniform mat4 modelViewProjection;  
varying highp vec2 pos;  
varying vec2 texCoord;  
void main() {  
    texCoord = vec2(textureCoordinate.s, 1.0 - textureCoordinate.t) ;  
    gl_Position = modelViewProjection * position;  
    pos = vec2(position.x, 1.0 - position.y);  
}
```

My fragment shader is:

```
precision highp float;  
uniform sampler2D yourTexture;  
varying highp vec2 texCoord;  
varying highp vec2 pos;  
void main() {  
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(yourTexture, vec2(pos.x, pos.y));  
}
```

I just can't seem to get the texture at the bottom left spread out across the surface. Could you please help?

[image: This is what is rendered when I run the code]

Doing some manual vertex and frag shader juggling, I can get the result but it feels very inelegant and I am pretty sure it should not be writing specific code like this.

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 textureCoordinate;
uniform mat4 modelViewProjection;
varying highp vec2 pos;

varying vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    // Pass along to the fragment shader
    texCoord = vec2(textureCoordinate.s, 1.0 - textureCoordinate.t) ;

    // output the projected position
    gl_Position = modelViewProjection * position;
    pos = vec2(position.x, position.y);
}
```

Changes to fragment shader (where 0.4 is the slope of the top of the quad):

```
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D yourTexture;
varying highp vec2 texCoord;
varying highp vec2 pos;


void main() {

    gl_FragColor = texture2D(yourTexture, vec2(pos.x/5.0, 1.0 - pos.y/(3.0+0.4*pos.x)));
//    gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.0, pos.y/5.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Which gives me exactly what I am looking for but it feels very wrong way of doing things.

[image]

EDIT: I am using the `pos` variable instead of texCoord as the `texCoord` is giving me weird as hell results which I can't really understand :(.

If I was to modify my fragment shader as:

```
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D yourTexture;
varying highp vec2 texCoord;
varying highp vec2 pos;

void main() {

//    gl_FragColor = texture2D(yourTexture, vec2(pos.x/5.0, 1.0 - pos.y/(3.0+0.4*pos.x)));
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(yourTexture, texCoord);

//    gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.0, pos.y/5.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I get something like the pic below:
[image]

Which says to me that there is something wrong with my texture coordinates definition but I can't figure out what?

EDIT2: OK progress. Based on an answer that Lock gave on a related thread I redefined my uvs using the method below:

```
let uvSource = SCNGeometrySource(data: uvData,
            semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord,
            vectorCount: textureCord.count,
            floatComponents: true,
            componentsPerVector: 3,
            bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float),
            dataOffset: 0,
            dataStride: sizeof(vector_float2))
```

Now it gives me a result like this when I use texCoord in my frag shader:

[image]

Its not as great as the curved deformities I get in the texture above. But its progress. Any ideas how can I get it to smooth out like pic 2 in this Massive question?

Kindly help.

Comment: Nice work @AdiTheExplorer . You just need to adjust the top left texture coordinate, instead of 0,1 it's going to be at 0,0.6 (3/5) to stop the deformation. FWIW, I don't see what's wrong with the code you had for generating the texture coordinates, but obviously something wasn't quite right with it.

Comment: Thanks @lock. But I actually do want it to deform like in pic 2 in this thread to get that nice curve going in the texture? Where its deforming evenly across the 2 triangles.

You've Been a great help by the way. Couldn't have done it without it :)

Comment: Fair enough. In that case it's probably the top right coordinate you want to tweak, making this y coordinate lower will stretch it up. It probably still wont give you the deformation you see in figure 2, that's a creative equation you've got for calculating the texture coordinates. You can probably replicate this using the uv's, now that they're ok (`gl_FragColor = texture2D(yourTexture, vec2(texCoord.x, texCoord.y/(0.4*texCoord.x)));` maybe...).  BUT, generally your texture image would have the deformation already in it allowing the use of standard shaders.

Answer (score 7):

in the fragment shader you have to use `texCoord` instead of `pos` to sample your texture.

Also note that you don't need a program to texture an arbitrary geometry. You can use regular material for custom geometries too. If you want to do something that's not possible with a regular material, you can also have a look at shader modifiers, they are easier to use than programs and don't require you to manually handle lights for instance.

Comment: I used that but it gives me weird results...the pos variable seems to work better. The texCoord is there from when I initially wrote the code and failed :(

Comment: Still stuck on this :(